# Get selected value ajax

Tags: php, ajax

First Select

```
<Select id="drop1" onchange="drop1(this.value)">
<option value ='1'>1</option
<option value ='2'>2</option
<option value ='3'>3</option
</select>

<div id = "txtHint1"></div>
```

Once a value has been selected, the value will be sent to ajax. And corresponding dropdown will be generated on another page and show in div txthint1.

Second Select

```
<Select id="drop2" onchange="drop2(this.value)">
<option value ='111'>111</option
<option value ='222'>222</option
<option value ='333'>333</option
</select>

<div id = "txtHint2"></div>
```

As the generated dropdown is another php page, how can I get what the value the user has selected to show on my current page (div txthint2)?

I will be working in php.

```
$value = $_GET['a'];
```

There are no submitted button.

Comment: what do you mean "on another page" if you are submitting the form then there is no need for ajax

Comment: The other php page, which loads the 2nd dropdown using ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send out the second request on a successful response:

```
function one() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function() {
            two(TheValueFromOne);
        }
    });
}

function two() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}
```

What is happening is that once the request has been made successfully, then it is automatically starting the next request right after.

However, if you are jsut passing values around form one page to another you really do not need AJAX.

### FOR EXAMPLE:

test1.php:

```
<form action="test2.php" method="get">
Book Title <br />
<input type="text" name="booktitle" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value=" - Update Database - " />
</form>
```

test2.php

```
<body>
<? echo $_GET["booktitle"]; ?>
</body>
```

### IN YOUR CASE:

test1.php:

```
<Select id="drop1" name="test1">
<option value ='1'>1</option
<option value ='2'>2</option
<option value ='3'>3</option
</select>
```

test2.php

```
<Select id="drop1">
<option selected = "<? echo $_POST['test1']; ?>"></option>
<option value ='1'>1</option
<option value ='2'>2</option
<option value ='3'>3</option
</select>
```

### @QUESTION:

```
<div id = "txtHint2"><? echo $_POST['test1']; ?></div>
```

### @POSTING WITH FORM:

```
<form method="post" action="test2.php" >

<Select id="drop1" name="test1" onChange="this.parentNode.submit()">
<option value ='1'>1</option
<option value ='2'>2</option
<option value ='3'>3</option
</select>

</form>
```

Comment: But it will need to know what selected value it has been selected. Sorry, I forgot to mention im doing it in php so the page will already be loaded

Comment: So let me get this straight. You select a value from a drop down, then you want to pass that value to the next page into the next dropdown?

Comment: correct and then on the next page it will also have a dropdown which will be shown on my current page in <div id = 'txtHint1></div>. Whatever the user selects on the next page dropdown, I want to show on my current page using <div id 'txtHint2'></div>. Is this possible?

Comment: 'In my case' part is correct, that similar to what I got. And whatever the userselected in that dropdown will be shown on my current page by div id =texthint2? Possible?

Comment: it will work if you are encapsulating your values inside of a form. you can then use a javascript event to make a post on select event or using a form submit button.